# Can't figure out why a page will not load for some users

Tags: javascript, php

I am at a loss and need any advice I can get on what to try next.

I have a site where users can edit their profiles. We have about 10K customers. Of those customers about 20 have this issue and I can't figure it out. When they go to the page it acts like it doesn't finish loading. One symptom is when you hover over links the pointer will not change to hand.

For me I can login with their account and try different machines and browsers and it works perfectly. I can use Chrome and change the speed and view type all still works. I have never actually reproduced the issue.

They can hit CTRL+F5, clear cache, try different browsers, different systems, nothing works for them. Today I worked with one person and removed everything from loading on that page except for exactly what was needed. No Google Analytics, no FB pixel, stripped all the JS, and nothing helped. He even tried at his local library and it still happened.

I am totally out of ideas. Anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: You can login with their account? What site is this just so I know never to submit my details. I hope you at least hash passwords if not I hope you clearly point that out in the terms.

Comment: @NewToJS passwords are for mere users, not for us developers with god-like powers (e.g. the ability to fake session data)

Comment: @rjdown It's still worrying people sign up to a site and the owner logs in under their account. Privacy issues much? I get it the owner can look on the database and see everything same with any data uploaded to the site but as an owner/developer you respect your client privacy.

Comment: It's not worrying at all, it's pretty clear that he's working WITH the customers to solve their issues.

Comment: if you're storing sessions, then you absolutely can log in as that user. No passwords, no user data - just a session hash. Oh and @T3chn0crat, you will need to post some code. Look over your access logs, find matching requests.

Comment: What do these 20 customers have in common: region? slow internet?

Comment: Have you tried older browsers? Some clients may be using things like IE8

Comment: @trincot Its hard to get them to answer because usually they are upset things don't work.  But they are from all over the US.  This user was on high speed Internet.

Comment: @Jujunol They have all been using modern browsers.  I do not believe it to be the browser at this point.

Comment: @eggmatters good thought on the logs, but he goes from the login, right to the profile, and only gets 200s and 304s the whole time.  I am not sure what code it could be at this point.  I have stripped almost everything.  I am going to have him try to disable javascript next just to see.

Answer (score 0):

The page likely isn't "acting" like it's not finishing loading, it probably is not finishing loading. Your sample size is probably large enough to cover users with outmoded browsers or restricted bandwidth. You *need* to get more info from your users: OS & version, Browser, Virus protection.
If you're relying on GA and other 3rd party libs acquired by CDN, one downed delivery network can stop the entire page.
I've seen this happen while on a vpn. Ask your users if they're on a VPN when this happens. Some of your assets (googlefont api for example) will not load over crappy VPN's.

Comment: The user I worked with today had Win10 with IE 11 and because well its IE he tried Firefox as well.  Same issue.  Then he tried Safari on his iPad and Firefox from him library same issue.

Comment: what about anti virus software? Does your user have cookies disabled? Do you use session cookies? It's good (and rare) you have a user like this willing to work with you to this capacity. PM me if you're still at a loss and I may be of more assistance.